# Dynamically Binding Items in ListVIew

Tags: javascript, listview, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

In my Windows 8 JavaScript application, I have a ListView.  I need to add either a message or link to a row, depending on what the current user's status is.  So I essentially need to show or hide items depending on some flag.  How, using the JavaScript API of the ListView, do I parse items at an item level?  There is no collection of items on the ListView control per the MSDN, and I need to have access to the data and the item at the row level.

I'm sure I'm missing it somehow, just getting into this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on what your trying to do, but I'll give it a shot.
If you need to conditionally show or hide items (or certain parts of an item) there and a couple of ways you can go.

The first is to create an imperative template render function. First, tell you ListView that its item template is a function with something like `myListView.itemTemplate = myCustomFunction`. Then write a function like:

```
function myCustomFunction(itemPromise) {
    //you have to return a promise
    return itemPromise.then(function (item) {
        //get the right item template (declared in your HTML),
        //render the item data into it, and return the result
        var itemTemplate;
        if (item.data.key === "foo")
            itemTemplate = q("#fooItemTemplate", element); //return foo template
        else if (item.data.key === "bar")
            itemTemplate = q("#barItemTemplate", element);
        return itemTemplate.winControl.render(item.data);
    });
}
```

If one of the item templates has explicit style code to show or hide part and the other doesn't then you'll get the result you're looking for.

Another way is to wait until the ListView is finished loading and then traverse and manipulate the DOM according to your conditions.

To capture the moment your ListView finishes loading do this:

```
myListViewControl.onloadingstatechanged = function (e) {
    if (myListViewControl.loadingState == "complete") {
        ...
    }
}
```

The ListView goes through a few loading states as it's loading and the last is "complete". When it's complete, you can use the awesome power of CSS selectors and the new querySelector/querySelectorAll method that ECMAScript 5 gives us to find all of the ListView items like this:

```
myListView.querySelectorAll(".win-item")
```

That would return a NodeList of all of the ListView items and you can use your ninja skills in DOM manipulation to have your way with them.

Hope that helps!!

P.S. Check out codeSHOW to learn more HTML/JS dev in Windows 8 ([aka.ms/codeshowapp](http://aka.ms/codeshowapp) | [codeshow.codeplex.com](http://codeshow.codeplex.com))